# Read directory and put each subdirectories in one line of txt file

Tags: bash

I want to read the subdirectory tree and save the name of each one in a txt file. One line for each subdirectory.

```
echo $(ls -li $dir/*/*) >> $checkFile
```

With this code it puts all the subdirectories in a single line in the txt file, but it also stores the path of each subdirectory. I just want the name of the directory I've read.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find`:

```
find "${dir}" -type d -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -printf "%f\n"
```

Please read [Why not parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Hi, thanks just now i'm trying `tree -d -L 3`but this not separate de output in different lines with every directory